# Can't Redirect HTTP to HTTPS on wampserver on azure

Tags: azure, wamp, wampserver, httpd.conf, http-redirect

I installed the wamp server on the azure virtual machine to put my website there,
then it encountered an problem where my website could not be accessed using
**http**, and can only be accessed by **https**, azure configuration already allows all traffic from port 80
I have configured the .htacces settings in the www folder like this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://sdh.or.id/$1 [R=301,L,NE]

# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

httpd.conf configuration like this :

```
    # prevent Apache from glomming onto all bound IP addresses.
    #
    #Listen 12.34.56.78:80
    Listen 0.0.0.0:80
    Listen [::0]:80    
#
# Dynamic Shared Object (DSO) Support
```

and this problem is still continues today, is there anyone who can help?

Comment: Did you also allow access on port 443, the https port